# Overwriting spring-boot autoconfiguration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm a little bit confused with the behaviour of spring-boot when overwriting specific autoconfigurations.

I like to partly overwrite the BatchAutoConfiguration, but I guess, my question is not specific to BatchAutoConfiguration.
Actually, I just want to "overwrite" two methods of this class:
`public BatchDatabaseInitializer batchDatabaseInitializer()` and `public ExitCodeGenerator jobExecutionExitCodeGenerator()`.

Therefore, I've written the following code:
    package ch.test.autoconfig.autoconfigure;

```
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.boot.ExitCodeGenerator;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigureAfter;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigureBefore;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchDatabaseInitializer;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobExecutionExitCodeGenerator;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnBean;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnClass;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnMissingBean;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcOperations;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

/**
 * I'm using the same annotations as defined in BatchAutoConfiguration...
 */
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass({ JobLauncher.class, DataSource.class, JdbcOperations.class })
@AutoConfigureAfter(HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class)
@ConditionalOnBean(JobLauncher.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(BatchProperties.class)

// ... but I add @AutoConfigureBefore(BatchAutoConfiguration.class) to take precedence over BatchAutoConfiguration
@AutoConfigureBefore(BatchAutoConfiguration.class)
public class JavabatchAutoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    @ConditionalOnBean(DataSource.class)
    public BatchDatabaseInitializer batchDatabaseInitializer() {
        System.out.println("Entering overwritten batchDatabaseInitializer");
        return new BatchDatabaseInitializer();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public ExitCodeGenerator jobExecutionExitCodeGenerator() {
        System.out.println("Entering overwritten jobExecutionExitCodeGenerator");
        return new JobExecutionExitCodeGenerator();
    }
}
```

As mentioned in the code, I'm using the exact same annotions for the class and methods, as they are definend in `BatchAutoConfiguration.class`.
The only exception is adding `@AutoConfigureBefore(BatchAutoConfiguration.class)`. Since this should take precedence over BatchAutoConfiguration, I assumed, that this would kind of "overwrite" the original.

To test is, I use the following pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">


    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ch.test.autoconfig</groupId>
    <artifactId>auto_config_test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

And I'm using the this simple job with a main method:

```
package ch.test.autoconfig;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepContribution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.ChunkContext;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.Tasklet;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

/**
 * Created by U802552 on 01.06.2015.
 */
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MainJob {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory steps;

    @Bean
    protected Tasklet tasklet() {
        return new Tasklet() {
            public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution,
                                        ChunkContext context) {
                return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job() throws Exception {
        return this.jobs.get("job").start(step1()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    protected Step step1() throws Exception {
        return this.steps.get("step1").tasklet(tasklet()).build();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // switch on  Auto-Configuration-Report
        System.setProperty("debug","true");
        SpringApplication.run(MainJob.class, args);
    }
}
```

I would expect, that my two overwritten methods are called, but as the Auto-Configuration-Report states, my JavabatchAutoConfiguration class has a
"negative match" because of a missing "JobLauncher" instance. As the report also states, the original BatchAutoConfiguration class has a positive match for the same `ConditionalOnBean`check.

If I comment `@ConditionalOnBean(JobLauncher.class)`on the class and `@ConditionalOnBean(DataSource.class)`on the `batchDatabaseInitializer`-method, everything works as expected.

Does anybody have an explanation for this behaviour?

Thanks
Hansjörg

Comment: You are making it way to complex... Just add 2 beans of that type `BatchDatabaseInitializer` and `ExitCodeGenerator`. The Spring Batch auto configuration will detect those automatically and use those instead f the defaults. You don't need all the conditionals and configure after etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are making it way to complex. The only thing you need to do is create a configuration which defines the 2 specific beans you want to use.

```
@Configuration
public class MyBatchConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ExitCodeGenerator myExitCodeGenerator() {
        return new MyExitCodeGenerator();
    }

    @Bean
    public BatchDatabaseInitializer myBatchDatabaseInitializer() {
        return new MyBatchDatabaseInitializer();
    }

}
```

That is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think Hansjörg and M. are right. The "methode name" should be the same as the specific AutoConfiguration uses.

Reason: I am not sure, If the presence of the same type in the ApplicationContext is the only criteria for spring to omit creation of that type. At least the qualifier has to be the same?!